# how to change multiple rows in codeigniter by using update batch query

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: table structure]**Problem:**
I just want to update the bill by using unique id in my database but my problem is it showing the error as undefined index id..help me to resolve this error...

**Controller Code:**

```
public function Bill_Edit()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $query = $this->db->get('parmaster');    
    $data['PName']=$query->result_array();
    $data['r'] = $this->User_model->Bill_Edit1();
    $data['result'] =$this->User_model->Bill_Edit();
    $this->load->view('Inventory/Bill_Edit',$data);
}
```

**Model Code:**

```
public function Bill_Edit()
{
    $Search = $this->input->post('Search');
    $this->db->where('billno', $Search);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('salesitem');
    $this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $query;
}
public function Bill_Edit1()
{
    $Search = $this->input->post('Search');
    $this->db->where('billno', $Search);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('salesitem');
    $this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
    $query = $this->db->get()->row();
    return $query;
}
```

Below i have attached the error of my screenshot..Help me to fix this error

[image]

**Update batch code:**

```
public function Bill_Update($data) 
{  
    $LDate = $this->input->post('TDate');
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $LDate);
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $id =$this->input->post('billid'); 
    $billno = $this->input->post("billno");
    $data = $this->input->post(); 
    $count = count($data['Product_Code']); 
    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
        $entries[] = array( 
            'Id' => $data['billId'][$i],
             'Product_Code'=>$data['Product_Code'][$i], 
             'Prdtname'=>$data['Prdtname'][$i], 
             'Qty'=>$data['Qty'][$i], 
             'rate'=>$data['rate'][$i], 
             'billdate'=>$newDate, 
             'amount'=>$data['amount'][$i] 
        ); 
    } 
    $this->db->where('Id',$id);
    $this->db->update_batch('salesitem', $entries,'Id');
```

Comment: Check my edited code

Comment: The error is about batch update, but there's no updates in the posted code?

Comment: sorry forgotted to add upadte code..now check my code

Comment: done sir..check my edited code

Comment: It printing the values correctly when i have used print_r($entries) but that value is not updating in database

Comment: can you show us the printed values array

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in the below code

**Update batch code:**

```
public function Bill_Update($data) 
{  
    $LDate = $this->input->post('TDate');
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $LDate);
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $id =$this->input->post('billid'); 
    $billno = $this->input->post("billno");
    $data = $this->input->post(); 
    $count = count($data['Product_Code']); 
    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
        $entries[] = array( 
            'Id' => $data['billId'][$i],
             'Product_Code'=>$data['Product_Code'][$i], 
             'Prdtname'=>$data['Prdtname'][$i], 
             'Qty'=>$data['Qty'][$i], 
             'rate'=>$data['rate'][$i], 
             'billdate'=>$newDate, 
             'amount'=>$data['amount'][$i] 
        ); 
    } 
    $this->db->where('Id',$id);
    $this->db->update_batch('salesitem', $entries,'Id'); 
}
```

Change
**`'Id' => $data['billId'][$i],`** to **`'id' => $data['billId'][$i],`**

remove **`$this->db->where('Id',$id);`**

**`$this->db->update_batch('salesitem', $entries,'Id');`**  to  **`$this->db->update_batch('salesitem', $entries,'id');`**

And try again.

Comment: Tried sir..but now getting undefined index id error\